# C# calling WCF service function having user defined data type as parameter

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I want to call a wcf service function from my c# client, that service was at remote site. so need to call that function by dynamic linking the service.

On calling the function and passing the required parameters, it is throwing an exception that

> "Object of type 'TMsgInParam' cannot be converted
>   to type 'omni.infrasofttech.com.TMsgInParam'"

So I need to know how to pass the complex type parameters to that function.

Now here is the wsdl file data of that service to which i have to connect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/">
<s:element name="Invoke">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="aToken" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="aSerName" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="aMethod" type="s:int" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MsgInParam" type="tns:TMsgInParam" /> 
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="TMsgInParam">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field1" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field2" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field3" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field4" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field5" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:element name="InvokeResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InvokeResult" type="tns:TMsgOutParam" /> 
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="TMsgOutParam">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field1" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field2" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field3" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field4" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Field5" nillable="true" type="s:string" /> 
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="InvokeSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Invoke" /> 
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="InvokeSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:InvokeResponse" /> 
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="TOmniServiceSoap">
<wsdl:operation name="Invoke">
<wsdl:input message="tns:InvokeSoapIn" /> 
<wsdl:output message="tns:InvokeSoapOut" /> 
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="TOmniServiceSoap" type="tns:TOmniServiceSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
<wsdl:operation name="Invoke">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/Invoke" style="document" /> 
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="TOmniServiceSoap12" type="tns:TOmniServiceSoap">
<soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
<wsdl:operation name="Invoke">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/Invoke" style="document" /> 
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal" /> 
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TOmniService">
<wsdl:port name="TOmniServiceSoap" binding="tns:TOmniServiceSoap">
<soap:address location="http://192.168.100.108/PassOmni30/OmniService.asmx" /> 
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="TOmniServiceSoap12" binding="tns:TOmniServiceSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://192.168.100.108/PassOmni30/OmniService.asmx" /> 
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Now I am calling this service Invoke function by the following code

```
Uri mexAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.100.108:8080/PassOmni30/OmniService.asmx?wsdl");

// For MEX endpoints use a MEX address and a 
// mexMode of .MetadataExchange
MetadataExchangeClientMode mexMode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;

string contractName = "TOmniServiceSoap";
string operationName = "Invoke";

object[] operationParameters = new object[4];

TMsgInParam MsgInParam = new TMsgInParam();

MsgInParam.Field1 = "Name";
MsgInParam.Field2 = "Age";
MsgInParam.Field3 = "Address";
MsgInParam.Field4 = "DOB";
MsgInParam.Field5 = "Contact";

//add parameters
operationParameters[0] = "1";
operationParameters[1] = "1";
operationParameters[2] = 82;
operationParameters[3] = MsgInParam;

// Get the metadata file from the service.
MetadataExchangeClient mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(mexAddress, mexMode);
mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
MetadataSet metaSet = mexClient.GetMetadata();

// Import all contracts and endpoints
WsdlImporter importer = new WsdlImporter(metaSet);
Collection<ContractDescription> contracts = importer.ImportAllContracts();
ServiceEndpointCollection allEndpoints = importer.ImportAllEndpoints();

// Generate type information for each contract
ServiceContractGenerator generator = new ServiceContractGenerator();
var endpointsForContracts = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<ServiceEndpoint>>();

foreach (ContractDescription contract in contracts)
{
    generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract);

    // Keep a list of each contract's endpoints
    endpointsForContracts[contract.Name] = allEndpoints.Where(
        se => se.Contract.Name == contract.Name).ToList();
}

if (generator.Errors.Count != 0)
    throw new Exception("There were errors during code compilation.");

// Generate a code file for the contracts 
CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
options.BracingStyle = "C";
CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");

// Compile the code file to an in-memory assembly
// Don't forget to add all WCF-related assemblies as references
CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(
    new string[] { 
       "System.dll", "System.ServiceModel.dll", 
       "System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" });
compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

CompilerResults results = codeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, generator.TargetCompileUnit);

if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    throw new Exception("There were errors during generated code compilation");
}
else
{
    // Find the proxy type that was generated for the specified contract
    // (identified by a class that implements 
    // the contract and ICommunicationbject)
    Type clientProxyType = results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(
        t => t.IsClass &&
            t.GetInterface(contractName) != null &&
            t.GetInterface(typeof(ICommunicationObject).Name) != null);

    // Get the first service endpoint for the contract
    ServiceEndpoint se = endpointsForContracts[contractName].First();

    // Create an instance of the proxy
    // Pass the endpoint's binding and address as parameters
    // to the ctor
    object instance = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(
        clientProxyType.Name,
        false,
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance,
        null,
        new object[] { se.Binding, se.Address },
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

    // Get the operation's method, invoke it, and get the return value
    object retVal = instance.GetType().GetMethod(operationName).Invoke(instance, operationParameters);

    MessageBox.Show("Login reply received- " + retVal.ToString());
}
```

And defination of those complex datatype i have given is this in global scope

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/")]
public partial class TMsgInParam {

    private string field1Field;

    private string field2Field;

    private string field3Field;

    private string field4Field;

    private string field5Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field1 {
        get {
            return this.field1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field2 {
        get {
            return this.field2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field3 {
        get {
            return this.field3Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field3Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field4 {
        get {
            return this.field4Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field4Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field5 {
        get {
            return this.field5Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field5Field = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://omni.infrasofttech.com/")]
public partial class TMsgOutParam {

    private string field1Field;

    private string field2Field;

    private string field3Field;

    private string field4Field;

    private string field5Field;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field1 {
        get {
            return this.field1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field2 {
        get {
            return this.field2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field3 {
        get {
            return this.field3Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field3Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field4 {
        get {
            return this.field4Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field4Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Field5 {
        get {
            return this.field5Field;
        }
        set {
            this.field5Field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a namespace issue.  Even if they're structually the same, `omni.infrasofttech.com.TMsgInParam` is not the same object as `TMsgInParam` to the runtime or compiler.

Comment: actually I have tried by putting my defination of TMsgInParam in that same namesapce, still the same exception i am getting